# caroussel not displaying image in JS

Tags: javascript, html

i've a problem with my caroussel in JS
He just don't recognize my innerHTML, in fact when i look on the inspector, he don't recognize the  on my innerHTML, i've done some research and didn't found anything (showing

```
<img src = unknown/>.
```

My img array is an url array not in any folder.

Here's what i already have

```
 function slideShow() {
  var counter = 0;
  slideShow();
  const diapoImages = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652044049927-7142ea82c81d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639718561716-b59d3995d886?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653593349937-1a2a29a614d2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1742&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653629154297-d01874fe01c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653537649117-821e01f707c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
  ];

  var imgDiv = document.getElementById("header");

  if (counter < diapoImages.length) {
    var img = diapoImages[counter];
    imgDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${img}/>`;
    counter += 1; 
  }
  else {
    counter = 0; 
  }
  setTimeout(slideShow, 5000)
}
```

here's the HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c9b7852654.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Diaporama</title>
</head>
<body>
    <i id = "nav-gauche" class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i>
    <i id = "nav-droite" class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Javascript Caroussel</h1>
    <h2>Test d'un caroussel en JS</h2>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
</div>
<script src=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more of the HTML code?

Comment: The `<img src=${img}/>` template string will result in a `src` with no quotes, e.g. `src=abc` rather than `src="abc"`

Comment: yes just added to the question :)

Comment: How, when are you actually calling the slideshow function?

Comment: after the var counter = 0

Comment: Okay - 2 things. 1. You are calling it within itself so how does it start initially. 2. The way you are calling it within itself will cause an infinite loop after the counter declaration.

Comment: i've delete the call inside the function and pass it outside but nothing change

Comment: Moving the call outside the function does work, but you have more problems. Youve no loop for your counter so it just shows one image and then after 5 milliseconds runs again showing the same image. 
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Q9gP7Cufam

Comment: the thing is that even 1 image doesn't show up on my page i have <img src = unknown /> on the console

Comment: Its very difficult to debug an issue that cant be replicated. Have you looked at @DBS point and changed your code to match (adding quotes) - `<img src="${img}"/>`

Comment: @Christo I moved `setInterval(slideShow, 5000)` , `var counter = 0` and `slideShow()` outside of the function, works but is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the image tag using document.createElement("img"). Then, you should set the src of image tag. At the end of the function, you should append the image tag into the div tag.

```
function slideShow() {
        var counter = 0;
            slideShow();
            const diapoImages = [
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652044049927-7142ea82c81d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639718561716-b59d3995d886?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653593349937-1a2a29a614d2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1742&q=80",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653629154297-d01874fe01c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653537649117-821e01f707c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
            ];
    var imgDiv = document.getElementById("header");
    var image = document.createElement("img")
    for (var ind in diapoImages)       
        while ( ind < (diapoImages.length + 1)){       
            if (counter < diapoImages.length) {
                var img = diapoImages[counter];
                imgDiv.appendChild(image)
                counter += 1;
                image.src = img 
            }
            else {
                counter = 0; 
            }
        }
    }
    setTimeout(slideShow, 5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about innerHTML error, but I could see two important points that maybe help you.

- The line 3 (`slideShow();`) causes recursive calls.
- Whenever the function is invoked, line 2 (`counter = 0;`) will reset the value. So the second image will never be rendered.

```js
function slideShow(counter = 0) {
  const diapoImages = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1652044049927-7142ea82c81d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1639718561716-b59d3995d886?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653593349937-1a2a29a614d2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1742&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653629154297-d01874fe01c7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1653537649117-821e01f707c2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80",
  ];

  var imgDiv = document.getElementById("header");

  if (counter < diapoImages.length) {
    var img = diapoImages[counter];
    imgDiv.innerHTML = `<img src=${img}/>`;
    counter += 1;
  } else {
    counter = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(() => slideShow(counter), 5000)
}

slideShow();
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
```